# Set a file as the catch-all handler with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, xampp

This is what's in the root directory of the locally hosted web app

```
|- index.php
|- feed.php
|- .htaccess
```

I want to direct all the requests to `index.php`, no matter what the requested uri is. E.g., I want the server to execute `index.php` even if `feed.php` is typed into the address bar.

How should I configure the `.htaccess` file so that the server work as I intend it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the following in your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !index\.php /index.php [NC,L]
```